# Liferay: Render portlet contents differently based on view mode

Tags: jsf, liferay-6

I'd like to have different contents displayed when a portlet is in "normal mode" as opposed to "maximized mode". I'm using JSF as the view technology. Is there a check I can perform on the JSF end to check which view is currently being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging around on my own, I found out that `#{request.windowState}` gives you normal, maximized or minimized based on current view. Using this, there can be multiple solutions:

1. Do a `#{request.windowState == 'normal'}` check and conditionally
   display content.
2. Use `<ui:include src="#{request.windowState}.xhtml"
   />` in my main view and then create normal.xhtml and maximized.xhtml
   ui:composition files.